# Using IBM Watson Text-to-Speech with Postman?

Tags: postman, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

How do I use IBM Watson Text-to-Speech with Postman? To test I just want to get the list of voices. I set up a `GET` request with the url

```
https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/voices
```

Under `Headers` I set my `username` and `password`. 
[image]

Watson responded with:

```
{
  "code": 401,
  "error": "Not Authorized",
  "description": "No credentials supplied."
}
```

Where do the username and password go in Postman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See to the right of `Headers` it says `Authorization`. That is where authorization credentials go.

Each API can specify how they want authorization. If it is a username/password, it is considered "Basic Authorization".

You could technically put it under `Headers`, but you do not send your username and password as two separate fields. You would include one key-value header pair of `Authorization`: `Basic <Username:Password>` where `<Username:Password>` is Base 64 encoded.

Many APIs will have you sign in with Basic Authorization, and return a token to be used for all other APIs. You would then use Bearer Token.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jake G, that works perfectly!

[image]